# Remove specified of string, much like "remove" for arrays?

Tags: python, string

If I have a string, for example, "ASDFBOB DESUDESUBOBADSF", how can I remove all mentions of "bob" turning the line into "ASDF DESUDESUADSF"? It would be a great help, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str.replace`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) with a replacement of the empty string:

```
>>> x = 'ASDFBOB DESUDESUBOBADSF'
>>> y = x.replace('BOB', '')
>>> y
'ASDF DESUDESUADSF'
```

By default, that replaces *all* instances; if you only want to replace 1 (or up to N) instances, pass that in as the third parameter, e.g. `x.replace('BOB', '', 1)`.

If you need more powerful replacement functionality, such as case insensitivity or regular expressions, use [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) instead.

Comment: Why thank you!!! (I'll accept your answer when the thing lets me) Do you know how to count the amount of times that string appears, too? For example, 'ASDFBOB DESUDESUBOBADSF' would return 2? That would also help a lot! Also, it doesn't seem to work with '\n'. I have a string full of new line escapes I would like to remove, and doing .replace('\n', '') or .replace('\\n', '') doesn't work either...

Comment: @PlazmotechBinary: Use [`str.count`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) for that, assuming you only want to count the non-overlapping occurrences.  I suggest you read through the `str` class documentation to familiarize yourself with what string functions the Python standard libraries provide.

Comment: @PlazmotechBinary: Yes, it does work.  Remember that `str.replace` does not modify the current string, since strings are immutable -- it *returns* the new string.

Comment: Oh, right! Sorry it's 11:03 PM here, and I don't do stuff well when tired. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> "ASDFBOB DESUDESUBOBADSF".replace('BOB','')
'ASDF DESUDESUADSF'
```

Careful though, this is case sensitive.